# Using npm module (ogr2ogr) in lambda function returns no results

Tags: aws-lambda, promise, ogr, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to use the [ogr2gr module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ogr2ogr) in a lambda function but I'm having some issues with it, so I wanted to see if anyone tried to use the module in a lambda function? The way I am using the ogr2ogr module is by doing `.promise()`. However when I try to run my lambda function, I don't see anything in the logs. It seems like it just never hits the promise? Here is how my code looks like with the promise:

```
let data = await ogr2ogr(path)
            .destination(database)
            .options(['-f "PostgreSQL"', '-nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI', 'nln <schemaName>."' + tableName + '"', '-overwrite']).promise();
console.log(data);
```

I'm doing it exactly the way the documentation says but it still doesn't work. Something I should point out is that I tried to do

```
let ogr = ogr2ogr(path)
            .destination(database)
            .options(['-f "PostgreSQL"', '-nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI', 'nln <schemaName>."' + tableName + '"', '-overwrite']);
console.log(ogr);
```

And I actually see the EventEmitter in the logs:

```
EventEmitter {
  _inPath: '<path_of_file>',
  _onStderr: [Function (anonymous)],
  _driver: {},
  _args: [],
  _timeout: 15000,
  _format: 'GeoJSON',
  _skipfailures: false,
  _testClean: [Function (anonymous)],
  _destination: <database information>,
  _options: [
    '-f "PostgreSQL"',
    '-nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI',
    'nln useradministration.tableName',
    '-overwrite'
  ]
}
```

But if I try to do a callback like the documentation says, using the `.exec()` function, I don't see anything outputted:

```
        let ogr = ogr2ogr(path)
            .destination(database)
            .options(['-f "PostgreSQL"', '-nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI', 'nln <schemaName>."' + tableName + '"', '-overwrite']);
        console.log(ogr);
        
        ogr.exec(function (er, data) {
          if (er) {
            console.error(er);
          }
          console.log(data);
        });
```

I'm honestly stumped at this point and not sure what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated, like if anyone had a similar issue or maybe an explanation as to why the promise nor callback works in the lambda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my lambda timeout was at 3 seconds and the promise was taking longer than 3 seconds, resulting in the lambda timing out and me seeing no results in the logs.